# Python multiprocessing and Pandas - shared memory

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have 15 large dataframes (26000x2500 each). I currently have them as a dictionary of dataframes, but that can be changed if necessary.

I need to perform operations on each column (around 2500) and they are completely independent, so I figured it was a good candidate for parallel processing. At the moment, my code runs in a few hours, but I'd like to make it faster.

Here is my code structure:

**Main.py**

```
import Processor

# Build dataframes from CSV files
dataframes = ...
p = Processor(dataframes)
p.run()
```

**Processor.py**

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Processor():
    def __init__(self, dataframes):
        self._dataframes = dataframes

    def run():
        # Loop at each column
            # Launch new process and perform operations on column
            # Receive results back and store them
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the best way to achieve parallel processing, Process or Pool?
2. How can I share the dataframes in memory so I don't have to copy them to every thread/process?

Comment: Maybe Popen? You can simply divide your dataframes into 15 single csv files. then run multiple instances of your script and merge the results together afterwards.

Comment: My dataframes are already loaded in memory, I don't want to write them to CSV files and have each individual process read the whole dataframes just to use 1 column, I would quickly run out of memory. Unless I'm not understanding what you mean exactly.

Comment: With data of that size you really should be thinking spark -- but since it fits in your memory, if you do multiprocessing you'll eventually need to rebuild the dataframe as a pandas dataframe is not a multi-process safe object AFAIK.

Comment: I don't need to rebuild a dataframe afterwards. The 15 large dataframes can be read only. I need each subprocess to have access to them, perform operations and return something else once all processes are completed.

Comment: You cannot always tell whether Pandas choose to use view or copy. It also depends on if it is your actual task that slows things down. Does the non-parallel runtime makes sense compared to parallel one? Maybe use cProfile to see what is time-consuming.

Comment: I don't think this is a Pandas problem. I need a way to use shared memory to pass a dataframe. This should depend on the multiprocessing module, not Pandas. I did profile it with cProfile and it is the tasks within the loop that take up most of the time, so it would 100% benefit from parallel processing. I am not asking for different ways to do this, I know I want parallel processing and use the shared memory, so I'd like the answers to stay on topic :)

Comment: Sharing memory in using `multiprocessing` is much harder than doing it with `threading`. As Pandas is a c extension, you should not run into issues witth the GIL either, so I think you should go for multithreading rather than multiprocessing.

Comment: My understanding is that multithreading in Python is still blocked by the GIL-lock where only one thread can run at any given time within a single process. Since my application is CPU-intensive and doesn't have idle-time (such as waiting on network resources), multithreading wouldn't make my code benefit from parallel processing. Am I correct?

Comment: Not quite. In general the GIL blocks execution of multiple threads simultaneously when running threads in cPython. However, the GIL can be released at certain times, which allows other threads to execute, e.g. while waiting for IO **and** when running certain c extensions. Among those c extensions are `numpy`, `scipy` and `pandas`. Thus, as long as the main execution time happens within `pandas` calls, multithreading works fine, also for compute intense operations.